# File download giving alert message instead of downloading it

Tags: php

On button click I'm downloading a text file via PHP in AJAX.

Here is my code. I only get an alert of file contents instead of downloading the file.

```
<?php
$cpy1 = $_POST['cpy1'];

file_put_contents("download.txt",$cpy1);


 $file ="download_link.txt";

    if(!file_exists($file)) die("I'm sorry, the file doesn't seem to exist.");

    $type = filetype($file);
    // Get a date and timestamp
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    $time = time();
    // Send file headers
    header("Content-type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=download_link.txt");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
    header('Expires: 0');
    // Send the file contents.
    set_time_limit(0); 
    readfile($file);
?>
```

Help please.

Comment: You could check `download` HTML attribute, which is supported in most browsers by now. [check it out](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: Obviously `header("Content-type: file");` is not a correct mime type

Answer (score 0):

I got the desired OP by below code. Was created a hidden download btn (hyperlink of text file) and on success made a click on it

```
success: function(data){
   swal("Download List", data, "success");

   //  alert(data);
   $('#getfile')[0].click();
}
```

This gave popup with text file download

Answer (score -1):

I guess it just because of your third part application (e.g. IDM). Please disable/uninstall it first then your code should work as you want.